# How to get "all" (or the MAIN/LAUNCHER) android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

i want receive all start app intents (i think MAIN/LAUNCHER, see below) to log how often i used the application. So i do *not* want create an activity... I tried several receiver blocks, but for now nothing works:

with, without priority, only the action, both, only the category and so on..

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver" android:enabled="true"
    android:process=".e">
    <intent-filter priority="100000" android:priority="100000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Have anyone an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I want receive all start app intents

You cannot do that, sorry.

Comment: @Christoph - broadcast `Intents` and `Intents` for starting activities are two different things. You cannot define a `<receiver>` element to get control when an activity is started.